# Compiz-Snow Plug-In

Tags: linux, graphics

Looks nice: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtClcwRgJxU. How else can it be done?

Comment: Are you looking to do this at the console, the framebuffer console, the framebuffer, SVGALib programs, or X11? (I'm assuming X11, but it'd be best if you said exactly what you want...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about X11, you can write a Composite Manager to achieve this. Your composite manager would probably want to realize these effects with OpenGL, for that the texture_from_pixmap plays an important rule.

You can start from these two keywords. It may be an option to not write the whole thing yourself but write a plugin to Compiz instead. Another keyword :)